# Load vanilla javascript page with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a Reactjs web application at example.com

It has routes at example.com/subpage1  ... example.com/subpage2 ...etc.   Anything I go to at example.com/* loads my react app.

I'd like to let an existing vanilla javascript page load when someone goes to example.com/differentPageEntirely

How can I do this?

Comment: Assign a component to for that route and add an iframe for your JavaScript page. Assuming you have some HTML associated with JavaScript. Another option is to add JavaScript file to react component on that route.